# htaccess redirect - allow files for construction page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've tried to set up a htaccess redirect for everyone except me. It works fine...except that I have to write an exception for every file that the under construction page wants. This will take me a while and I'm certain there is a proper way to do it, I just cant find it.

I have tried this:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 205.97.194.334
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.domain.com/page.htm

<Files page.htm>
allow from all
</Files>
```

But I get an internal server error

What I have now is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^127\.0\.0\.1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mypage\.html$  

RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com/construct/mypage.html [R=302,L]
```

What can I add in this to allow everything in the /construct/ ?#

Thankyou

P.S. Can anyone tell me why the first attempt didn't work?

EDIT:

Ok I've added this, which allowed the files, however, it is only redirecting when the directory is entered. I.e. domain.com will redirect to the construction page, but domain.com/index.php and anything else will not redirect

```
# Redirect everyone who's not from your IP
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !00.00.00.00 [NC]
# Allow real files to be served
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !index.html$ http://subverb.net/construct/index.html [R=307,L]
```

Comment: Pleae define exactly (in the form of a list for example) what rules do you exactly want to fork foryour site. Do you want everyone to access everything EXCEPT /construct which is only accessable form the allowed IPs?

Comment: Sorry, while it's under construction I want to be the only one who can access the site, so I'm allowing my IP. But I want all of the files the construction page is using (which are inside the construct directory). At the moment it is working, but only redirecting when the home domain is entered. Any extension of it, even domain.com/index.php does not redirect.

Comment: The redirect is supposed to send everyone except me to contruct/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `/construct` to be available to **everyone else**, and you want them to be redirected to that URL when opening any other URL:

```
# IF not from your address
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.4\.5\.6$

# AND not for /construct directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/construct

# THEN sen them to /construct/index.html
RewriteRule (.*) /construct/index.html [R=307,L]
```

Comment: That still leaves me in the same position, the redirect only works if the member goes to the home directory, ie domain.com. If they go to anything else in the directory, or even just domain.com/index.php, or any subdirectories the redirect does not work. I want the entire domain blocked to everyone except me

Comment: @Michael Mallett Have you tried it out? In your example `domain.com/index.php` the condition `!^/construct` will be true, so will `(.*)` so the redirection will happen.

Comment: Ah, aplogies, I still had RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f in there which I have just removed. Thanks that works perfectly